# Посоветуйте книги по Qt для начинающих

Tags: c++, qt, книги

Посоветуйте книги по Qt для начинающих. Посмотрел Марк Саммерфилд - "Qt Профессиональное программирование" - 2011 - там все таки сложно. Посоветуйте книги или видео-учебные.
И вопрос, имеет ли смысл учиться работать с Qt одновременно с изучением С++ ?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, так как список литературы указан в описании метки [qt], где его и следует редактировать и дополнять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала самое лучшее - Макс Шлее "Qt 4.8. Профессиональное программирование на С++". Можно на ОЗОНе купить электронную версию.

По поводу изучения. Хотя Qt не требует от программиста быть гуру в С++, но все-таки основы знать надо, иначе будет очень трудно. Освойте основы С++: процедурное программирование, модель ООП (особенно обратите внимание на наследование, виртуальные функции и т.п. - в Qt это очень используется), основы шаблонов и основы STL. Этого вполне достаточно, чтобы перейти к Qt.

Comment: а можно её скачать.. Подписываюсь за Макса Шлее.

Comment: Вот как раз по 4.8 я что-то не встречал... Много где лежат предыдущие издания. Тоже сгодятся для начала. Если имеете ссылку для скачивания последней версии, киньте, плиз. А то у меня только in paper, кирпич огромный, не всегда удобно.

Comment: С++ я только начал, хотя есть небольшой опыт программирования на С#. спасибо, буду читать этого Шлее.

Comment: Ну вот сначала поучитесь основам на консольных программах, потом добро пожаловать в Qt.

Comment: да я учусь, но думал, может, получится распараллелить процессы :)

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю на счёт Макса Шлее, но я всё таки рекомендую пользоваться их встроенной документацией, потому что она у них написана очень подробно. Но всё же, если не знаете основ С++, то лучше сначала основы выучить, а потом браться за Qt.

Comment: Встроенная документация - на английском?

Comment: Встроенная документация - обязательно нужно пользоваться как справочником. Без нее никуда. Никакая книга не даст полного описания этого огромного фреймворка. Но основы, принципы, тем более начинающему по ней будет трудно учить. 

И да, она на английском.

Comment: Использую Макса Шлее, встроенную официальную документацию, гугл и stack overflow